# Popover done click event a new popover

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, popover

I want popover done click event a new popover. How could I do that?

[image: Screenshot]

```
popover custom class and get web service 

NSMutableDictionary *dictkey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



_VKSelection = [VKSelection customVKPopoverWithView:SELECTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE listArray:arrList selectedArray:selectedArray keyDictionary:dictkey inputType:inputType animation:SELECTION_ANIMATION_CROSS_DISSOLVE animationDuration:VK_SELECTION_DURATION isBGTransparent:NO borderColor:nil borderWidth:0 cornerRadius:4 contentFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 400)];


[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:VK_POPOVER_DURATION options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview: _VKSelection];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise and moved the descriptive title in body as description. I also edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces, so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit your question to provide any additional information in order to identify the specific problem because your description is not clear at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MZFormSheetPresentationController. https://cocoapods.org/pods/MZFormSheetPresentationController